# Inserting in a child table

Tags: oracle, database

The design of my database has a table named person and tables employee and student are specializations of the table person the relationship between tables is total and has an overlapping restriction.
 The problem is that I want to insert a student or  employee and that the parent table (person) is updated automatically but the DBMS says violated a referential integrity constraint
I am using oracle can someone help me?

Comment: homework assignment?  what have you tried?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "...the relationship between tables is total and has an overlapping restriction".  What are the columns on each of the tables?  What constraints exist between the tables? What triggers exist, and what do they do?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly you have one table per type ([TPT](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/28/inheritance-mapping-strategies-with-entity-framework-code-first-ctp5-part-2-table-per-type-tpt.aspx)) and an employee can never be a student and also the other way around.

I assume that your problem is that the constraint is checked immediately instead of using deferred checking. That means the constraints are checked when your transaction is finished - which gives you the possibility to insert an employee/student and let your trigger do its work and after that do the commit.

Information about deferred constraints: 
[Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/clauses002.htm) 
[More information](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17120/general005.htm)